# D3JS chart: Hovering on some transitioning elements while others are still transitioning too stops the execution of the chart animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working on a horizontal bar chart. I added  `transition` to the `width` attr of the `rect`s from 0 to the desired value and they worked fine. Then I added some `circle` elements and made them "appear" one after another using `delay`, tweening the `r` attribute from 0 to the desired `r` value as well, and everything went fine too. The visualization works as expected if I don't hover over any element before all of them have finished their transitions.

Both the `rect`s and `circle`s are tweening their `width` and `r` attributes at different delays, which makes some of them to be shown before others.

**The problem:** if I hover over any `rect` while the other elements have not finished their transitions, all of them suddenly stop transitioning their attributes. Hence, the desired final state of the whole chart is not reached, actually it becomes a mess. I can't figure out why hovering over an element can interfere with the expected behavior of other "apparently" independent elements.

```js
function draw(){
    
  var width =  $( window ).width() ;
  var height =  document.body.clientHeight  ;

  var data = [
    {country:"Pichonita", growth: 15},
    {country:"Andromeda", growth: 12},
    {country:"India", growth: 33},
    {country:"Indonesia", growth: 22},
    {country:"Russia", growth: 6},
    {country:"Mars", growth: 41},
    {country:"Pluton", growth: 16},
    {country:"Earth", growth: 24},
    {country:"Neptune", growth: 8}
  ]; 

    //set margins
    var margin = {top:30, right:30, bottom:30, left:40};
    var width = width - margin.left - margin.right*2.5;
    var height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    //set scales & ranges

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0,  width - 100])

    var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, height]).padding(.2)

    //draw the svg

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right * 3)
      .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left*2 + "," + margin.top  + ")")

      //force data

       data.forEach(function(d){
      return d.growth = +d.growth;
       });

      //set domains

      yScale.domain(data.map(d => d.country))

      xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, d=> d.growth)])

      //add X & Y axes and append the bars to Y axis

      var xAxis = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class",xAxis)
          .attr("transform","translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))

     var yAxis =  svg.append("g")
           .attr("class",yAxis)
           .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
           .selectAll("rect")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr("stroke","transparent")
           .attr("stroke-width",4)
           .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).transition().duration(600).attr("stroke","#6D2077").attr("stroke-width",3).style("fill","#6D2077")
            d3.selectAll(".textCircle").transition().duration(600)
           .attr("r",yScale.bandwidth() / 1.9)
           .attr("stroke","#6D2077")
           .attr("stroke-width",1)
       }) 
          
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(600)
    .attr("stroke","transparent")
          .attr("stroke-width",0)
          .style("fill","#00338D")
      d3.selectAll(".textCircle")
          .transition().duration(600)
     .attr("r", yScale.bandwidth() / 2)
          .attr("stroke","transparent")
    }) 
          .attr("class","bar")
          .attr("height",yScale.bandwidth())
          .attr("x",0.5)
          .attr("y",function(d){
           return  yScale(d.country)
         })
         .attr("width",0)
         .transition()
         .duration(3800)
         .delay( (d,i)=> (i+1) *200)
         .ease(d3.easeElastic)
         .attr("width", function(d){
           return xScale(d.growth)
         })
        .style("fill","#00338D")

        var newG = svg.append("g")
        
         newG.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class","textCircle")
        .attr("cx",d=> xScale(d.growth) )
        .attr("cy",d=> yScale(d.country) + yScale.bandwidth() / 2)
        .attr("r",0)
        .transition()
          .duration(1200)
        .delay( (d,i)=> (i+1) *450)
        .attr("r",yScale.bandwidth() / 2)
        .attr("opacity",1)
        .style("fill","#0091DA")
        .attr("stroke","transparent")
        }

  draw();

  $( window ).resize(function() {
    $("body").empty(); 
    draw();
  });
```

```css
html{ 
  height: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  min-height: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg{
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  shape-rendering:geometricPrecision;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things are getting messed up because you've added `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners that try to perform actions that conflict with the ongoing transition events. To fix the problem, don't add the `mouseover`/`mouseout` listeners until after the chart bars have performed their initial transition. You can add a listener for the end of the transition using `transition.on('end', function(){...}` and then add the mouse event listeners to the DOM elements once the transition has completed.

```
    d3.select('#whateverItIs')
    // stuff to do prior to transition
    .transition()
    // transition stuff
    .on('end', function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .on("mouseover", function() {
        // handler code here
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
        // handler code here
        })
    })
```

With your code:

```js
function draw() {

  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = document.body.clientHeight;

  var data = [{
      country: "Pichonita",
      growth: 15
    },
    {
      country: "Andromeda",
      growth: 12
    },
    {
      country: "India",
      growth: 33
    },
    {
      country: "Indonesia",
      growth: 22
    },
    {
      country: "Russia",
      growth: 6
    },
    {
      country: "Mars",
      growth: 41
    },
    {
      country: "Pluton",
      growth: 16
    },
    {
      country: "Earth",
      growth: 24
    },
    {
      country: "Neptune",
      growth: 8
    }
  ];

  //set margins
  var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  };
  var width = width - margin.left - margin.right * 2.5;
  var height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  //set scales & ranges

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width - 100])

  var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, height]).padding(.2)

  //draw the svg

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right * 3)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left * 2 + "," + margin.top + ")")

  //force data

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    return d.growth = +d.growth;
  });

  //set domains

  yScale.domain(data.map(d => d.country))

  xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.growth)])

  //add X & Y axes and append the bars to Y axis

  var xAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", xAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))

  var yAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", yAxis)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("stroke", "transparent")
    .attr("stroke-width", 4)
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", 0.5)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.country)
    })
    .attr("width", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(3800)
    .delay((d, i) => (i + 1) * 200)
    .ease(d3.easeElastic)
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.growth)
    })
    .style("fill", "#00338D")
    .on('end', function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .on("mouseover", function() {
          d3.select(this)
            .transition().duration(600)
            .attr("stroke", "#6D2077")
            .attr("stroke-width", 3)
            .style("fill", "#6D2077")
          d3.selectAll(".textCircle")
            .transition().duration(600)
            .attr("r", yScale.bandwidth() / 1.9)
            .attr("stroke", "#6D2077")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
          d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(600)
            .attr("stroke", "transparent")
            .attr("stroke-width", 0)
            .style("fill", "#00338D")
          d3.selectAll(".textCircle")
            .transition().duration(600)
            .attr("r", yScale.bandwidth() / 2)
            .attr("stroke", "transparent")
        })

    })

  var newG = svg.append("g")

  newG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "textCircle")
    .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.growth))
    .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.country) + yScale.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr("r", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1200)
    .delay((d, i) => (i + 1) * 450)
    .attr("r", yScale.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", "#0091DA")
    .attr("stroke", "transparent")
}

draw();

$(window).resize(function() {
  $("body").empty();
  draw();
});
```

```css
html{ 
  height: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  min-height: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg{
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  shape-rendering:geometricPrecision;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @i alarmed alien that's almost perfect! But there's still a little bug. Even after forcing the bars to do nothing until the initial transition has ended using ´.on("end")´, if I hover  in and out constanly on the bars while the initial animation is happenining the last circle grows in black... Some how the transition of the circles are being affected by hovering over the bars even though the .´on("end")´. Please try doing several mouseover and mouse out while the bars are transitioning and see that the last ´circle´ still gets affected 
by this event.